# How do I change the name of the OS entry in GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2

I wanted to create my own operating system, so I created a distro image with archiso. It's pretty cool!

I created a python file that helps to automate the installation of my distro.

And there is the part that transfers the file to the chroot and then later installs GRUB. It works, but after restarting and the system already installed appears as "Arch Linux".

In the installation file I made in Python, I use the line `os.system("COMMAND LINUX")` to execute Linux commands

Is there any command or file I need to change to rename Arch Linux to my distro name? To put it in the installation automation file after installing GRUB so that after the person restarting it already appears "My OS"

PS: Don't tell me to change the menuentry of /boot/grub/grub.cfg, because it automatically overrides.

Comment: Look at these (2) files: `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/os-release`; you'll need to upgrade GRUB after modifying the 1st file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is generated?

There is a collection of scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` which are executed by `grub2-mkconfig` to create the `grub.cfg` file. Usually, the script named `10_linux` will be responsible for creating the actual boot menu items for the current distribution. If you have two or more OSs installed the `30_os-prober` might be the script that creates the menu items for the other OSs.

At least in Debian, the `10_linux` gets the name of the distribution from the variable `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` which is set in `/etc/default/grub`. But even in there, the value is set indirectly, using the command `lsb_release -i -s`.

So you could just change how the `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` variable is set in `/etc/default/grub` to quickly change the name of the distribution visible in GRUB.

But you might also want to examine the actual `/usr/bin/lsb_release` command (assuming Arch has that too). Turns out it is a Python script. If you change the way this script gets the name of the distribution to make it output the result "My OS", this would automatically change the name visible in GRUB, but since the `lsb_release` command can be used in multiple places, changing the script might allow you to get the name "My OS" at once to many other places, not just into GRUB menu.

But if the package management system also uses the information provided by the `lsb_release` command, changing the OS name there might make it harder to use Arch's software packages in your customized distribution. If you just want your distribution to be a "pre-customized version of Arch", you might not want that.

Comment: Thanks, i will try and then i will respond

Comment: I checked the /etc/default/grub file but im a little confused...
I found the GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR variable but it says "Arch"
And in GRUB says Arch Linux
Its a bug or is like that?